# MongoDB server won't install because of sufficient privileges

Tags: mongodb, privileges

Error that comes up when I try to install MongoDB community server: Service 'MongoDB server' (MongoDB) could not be installed. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services.

I chose to do a custom installation to change where I installed my program and to ignore mongodb compass installation.